# Studying analysis 2 from Munkres and Spivak

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, manifolds, self-learning

I'm studying analysis 2 and I'm having trouble studying the theorems.  For example, I'm using munkres' analysis on manifolds text and when I'm reading the chapter focusing on the inverse function theorem I'm not sure how to properly read the chapter.  There are lemmas and definitions before the theorem is stated then subsequently proved but I'm not sure how I as a reader am supposed to treat this material.  Should I make sure that I clearly understand every line of the theorem and then every line of the proof? Should I find a summary of the theorem elsewhere and jump to solving problems in the exercises to get a better feel for the theorem? Any advice on how study this material will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: I believe you could do it either way. There are some theorems whose proofs are to be promptly forgotten after you read through once (or ten times).

Comment: interesting comment.  So what should I be taking from the part of the chapter preceding the exercises; just understand what the theorems imply so that I can use them to solve problems?

Comment: You can just understand the statement of the theorem, work it out in some examples and see that it's true, solve some exercises and then return to the proof. (I am definitely *not* advocating skipping the proof.) In practice, I think you will rarely require to know the proof. However the theorem is important, and is the basis on which whole theories work (e.g. the theory of differentiable manifolds).